# Improve performance of moving a growing, large number of files in a mounted folder

Tags: python, performance, file-io, mount

This is my situation:

A have a Windows network share, i mount with `mount -t cifs -o username=username,password=password,rw,nounix,iocharset=utf8,file_mode=0777,dir_mode=0777 //192.168.1.120/storage /mnt/storage`

This folder contains a very rapidly growing number of files of various size (few byte up to ~20MB). If not moved/deleted the number of files in this directory may exceed 10 million.

I am required to move batches (in `move_script`) of files with a specific name (`*.fext`) from this directory to another directory (currently a subfolder in the directory `/mnt/storage/in_progress`).

Then the script starts another script (`process_script`) which will process the files in `/mnt/storage/in_progress`. After `process_script` finished, the files are moved again by `move_script` to another subdirectory (`/mnt/storage/done`). The *move-process-move* continues until the source folder (`/mnt/storage`) contains no more files.

Additional information of the process:

- the current bottleneck is the moving of the files (the files are moved a little faster than the files are created in the directory)

  ```
  if len(os.listdir("/mnt/storage") >= batch_size:
      i = 0
      for f in os.listdir("/mnt/storage"):
          if f.endswith(".fext"):
              move("/mnt/storage/+"f","/mnt/storage/in_progress"
              i+=1
          if i==batch_size:
              break
  ```
- the script moving/starting the processing of the files, waits for the processing to finish
- processing of the files in `/mnt/storage/in_progress` is fastest with batches of 1k-2k files.
- I have tried to have the number of files that are moved growing. First move 1k, then if the number of files in the source directory is growing, double number of files that are moved.. This slows down the processing of the files in `process_script`, but helps to keep up with the "file-generator"..
- I considered to simply rename the subdirectory `/mnt/storage/in_progress`, after `process_script` finished to `"/mnt/storage/done"+i_counter` and create a new `/mnt/storage/in_progress`. I assume this would half the move-time in the script.

I'll need to speed up the process, in order to keep up with the file-generator. How could I increase the performance of this move operation?

I'm open for any suggestion and willing to completely change my current approach.

edit: The scripts run on debian wheezy, so I theoretically could use a subprocess issuing `mv`, but I have no clue how reasonable that would be.

==========================================

edit2:
I wrote a script to test the speed differences between the various methods of moving.
First created 1x5GB (`dd if=/dev/urandom of=/mnt/storage/source/test.file bs=100M count=50`), then with 100x5MB (`for i in {1..100}; do dd if=/dev/urandom of=/mnt/storage/source/file$i bs=1M count=5`) and finally with 10000x5kB (`for i in {1..100000}; do dd if=/dev/urandom of=/mnt/storage/source/file$i bs=1k count=5`)

```
from shutil import move
from os import rename
from datetime import datetime
import subprocess
import os

print("Subprocess mv: for every file in directory..")
s = datetime.now()
for f in os.listdir("/mnt/storage/source/"):
    try:
        subprocess.call(["mv /mnt/storage/source/"+str(f)+" /mnt/storage/mv"],shell=True)
    except Exception as e:
        print(str(e))
e = datetime.now()
print("took {}".format(e-s)+"\n")

print("Subprocessmv : directory/*..")
s = datetime.now()
try:
    subprocess.call(["mv /mnt/storage/mv/* /mnt/storage/mvf"],shell=True)
except Exception as e:
    print(str(e))
e = datetime.now()
print("took {}".format(e-s)+"\n")


print("shutil.move: for every file file in directory..")
s = datetime.now()
for f in os.listdir("/mnt/storage/mvf/"):
    try:    
        move("/mnt/storage/mvf/"+str(f),"/mnt/storage/move")
    except Exception as e:
        print(str(e))
e = datetime.now()
print("took {}".format(e-s)+"\n")

print("os.rename: for every file in directory..")
s = datetime.now()
for f in os.listdir("/mnt/storage/move/"):
    try:
        rename("/mnt/storage/move/"+str(f),"/mnt/storage/rename/"+str(f))
    except Exception as e:
        print(str(e))
e = datetime.now()
print("took {}".format(e-s)+"\n")


if os.path.isdir("/mnt/storage/rename_new"):
    rmtree('/mnt/storage/rename_new')
print("os.rename & os.mkdir: rename source dir to destination & make new source dir..")
s = datetime.now()
rename("/mnt/storage/rename/","/mnt/storage/rename_new")
os.mkdir("/mnt/storage/rename/")
e = datetime.now()
print("took {}".format(e-s)+"\n")
```

Which revealed that there's not that much of a difference.. The 5GB file was moved really fast, which tells me that the moving, by altering the file table works. Here are the results of the 10000*5kB files (It felt like the results depend on the current network workload. e.g. the first `mv` test took 2m 28s, than later with the same files 3m 22s, also was `os.rename()` the fastest method most of the times..):

```
Subprocess mv: for every file in directory..
took 0:02:47.665174

Subprocessmv : directory/*..
took 0:01:40.087872

shutil.move: for every file file in directory..
took 0:01:48.454184

os.rename: for every file in directory..
rename took 0:02:05.597933

os.rename & os.mkdir: rename source dir to destination & make new source dir..
took 0:00:00.005704
```

Comment: Do you have a lock mechanism between the fext file generator and your script? Right now, regardless of which method you use, it appears you have a race condition where your script could be moving partially-written fext files.

Comment: The fext file generator will name, as long as they are not finished writing something like `file0001.fext.temp` and after writing/closing the files renames them to `file0001.fext` thus my script should never touch a file that is being written.

Answer (score 2):

You can simplify the code by using the `glob` module to list the files. But most likely the limiting factor is the network. Most likely the files end up being copied over the network instead of simply moved. Otherwise that process would be very fast.

Try using `os.rename()` to move the files. It may not work on a cifs filesystem, but it's worth a try. That should do an actual rename, not a copy. If it doesn't work, you may need to mount that filesystem some other way. Or run the moving process on the machine where the filesystem exists.

Comment: thank you very much for the comment. As for `glob` - this would definitely simplify but probably not speed up the code. `os.rename()` is a thin wrapper for the OSs `mv` so it *should* still be the same as I've tried `mv`, but I will definitely try to use `os.rename()`.

I've also considered to run the `move_script` on the computer, where the share is, but I won't not get access. And I have no idea how to improve the mounting - as all used directories are the same mountpoint it *should* move them (theoretically just alter the file table, I think)

Answer (score 1):

Peel the onion by logging in to the CIFS server and checking if even it can do a quick move of the files without copying them.

If you find it still does a copy, check the mounts on the CIFS server. It could be that behind the scenes, `/mnt/storage/in_progress` and/or `/mnt/storage/done` are actually different file systems or hard drives mounted under `/mnt/storage`, but shared out through the one CIFS share.

EDIT: Daedalus Mythos's timing test update shows that this is unlikely the case, since Daedalus can move a large 5 GB file very quickly, but can't move thousands of smaller files as quickly.

Answer (score 1):

This is a perfect case of asking the file generator developer to put the `*.fext` files in their own subdirectory, for example `/mnt/storage/fext_raw`, so you can just rename the whole directory to `/mnt/storage/in_progress` and then recreate `/mnt/storage/fext_raw`.

Comment: this is what I asked, as soon as I realized that what I'm doing is too slow. but apparently that is unacceptable.

Comment: Any reason given why? Maybe there's a compromise.

Comment: Their excuse was that the file generator keeps no track of the number of files it wrote, and it's main purpose doesn't require it to do so. Thus they don't want to add the feature.